# How to print using jquery with styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use jQuery to print out a webpage, but the styles are missing. I looked on GitHub and it seems that the demo that the author created seems to suffer the same problem. Does anyone know how to fix it?

In this demo, the styles are not being applied
http://doersguild.github.io/jQuery.print/demo/

When you click "print page" the text labelled "Element 1", "Element 2", etc show up in black, not red. What is the issue?

I have "Background graphics" enabled in my browser